# List of Artist Name in iTunes Music Store

Tags: ios, itunes-store

I want to get all artist name in iTunes.
I look this page but did not find any solution.
http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html
Is it possible to get list of Artist Name in iTunes Music store?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible with the current API.  You might be able to "fake" it depending on what you are trying to implement with multiple calls to search but you most likely won't be able to compose a complete list.

Keep in mind the search limit is 200 so you will probably be interested in the cache architecture at the bottom of the documentation: http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

Comment: savner thanks for reply . any other api through which i get artist names?
I only want list of music artist names

Comment: You can give the unofficial google music api a try. It looks promising https://github.com/simon-weber/Unofficial-Google-Music-API.  Won't be iTunes specific but should provide decent list.